# How to add a HTML submit quiz with correct and incorrect alert

Tags: javascript, html, forms, text

I have created a mini website, to teach myself JavaScript and PHP, the idea being that when you hit "play" you can guess a city by cllicking on the tiles to uncover the city in the background. I have the page working for this here: http://hoverpixel.netii.net/play.html

However I'm struggling to add the PHP/ JS to the text entry form.

Essentially I need to use a submit form to say:

1. When New York is entered - correct well done! (either as text or an alert)
2. Or when anything else is submitted - wrong try again!

I've searched everywhere for HTML submit forms that incorporate this functionality but have had no luck whatsoever :/

Please could someone point me in the right direction, or send a link to a sample code that has this functionality that I can edit?

Many thanks, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A thing you need is the attribute `action` for html forms: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/form/action

That allows you to send the entered data to your server. You can then access it using for example php's `$_POST`: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php
(Assuming you use the form's action method 'post' as well.)

Then, you can easily check whether the correct string was entered in your php code and then output the correct html, letting the user know whether they entered the correct string.

Hope this helps!
Feel free to ask for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try with jQuery:

**In test.php**

```
...
$data['status'] = 1; // Status of the operation (1: Ok, 0: Error)
$data['msg'] = $msg; // Error message or success
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

**In test.js:**

```
$("#send").click(function () {
    $.post('test.php', $('#yourForm').serialize(), function(data){
        if(data.status == 1){
            $('#result').show().addClass('success').html(data.msg);
        }
        else{
            $('#result').show().addClass('error').html(data.msg);
        }
    }, "json");
    return false;
});
```

**In test.html:**

```
<form method="post" id="yourForm">
...
<input id="send" type="button"/>
<span id="result"></span>
</form>
```

**In test.css:**

```
.success{
    color: blue;
}
.error{
    color: red;
}
```

Review:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
- http://www.electrictoolbox.com/json-data-jquery-php-mysql/

Hope that helps somewhat.

Regards.